# How to scrape and download pdfs from a list of URLs and name them based on other categorical variables?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a list of URLs that opens pdf file reports online. I could already download these pdfs and save them in my dropbox. However, instead of a general name, I would like to save them considering variables such as Year and the first 2 letters of the Filer Name. My database has more than 1000 observations.

I saved the first 46 pdf as:
`document_1.pdf document_2.pdf document_3.pdf`

However, I would like to save as:
`2014_Jo.pdf 2018_Pa.pdf 2019_Pe.pdf`

My database has this framework below:

| ` | Name | Year | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2014 | https://contributions.electionsbc.gov.bc.ca/pcs/lepublished/100126233.pdf |  |
| Paul | 2018 | https://contributions.electionsbc.gov.bc.ca/pcs/lepublished/100122323.pdf |  |

`

I can download the pdf's using the code bellow. But this code does not change names based on the variable name.

```
    `my_urls <- c(database$URL) 
     save_here <- paste0("document_", 1:46, ".pdf")
     mapply(download.file, my_urls, save_here)`
```

Comment: Since the answer works, you can click the checkmark next to answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

```
library(stringr)

my_urls <- database$URL
save_here <- paste0(database$Year,"_", str_sub(database$Name,1,2), ".pdf")
mapply(download.file, my_urls, save_here)
```

Note that this will save in whatever directory you're currently working in. If you want a different directory, you need to include path in `paste0`. For example, `paste0("C:\Users\b\docs\data\", database$Year, ...)`.